# Using Fiddler to sniff HTTPS requests of any process (Proxifier)

Tags: proxy, https, fiddler, trusted-root-certificates

As far as I understand Fiddler, it simply listens on localhost:8888 and changes the windows proxy settings to exactly that. So that every application that connects using that proxy sends the data through Fiddler.

The problem I'm having is that some applications don't care what the Windows proxy settings say and always try to connect directly.

So I was thinking.. shouldn't it be possible to just force specific processes to use a specific proxy?

And according to my research it actually seems to be possible. For example the application [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/new/ver3.htm) claims to be able to do it.

So I installed it, created a new profile, added a new HTTPS proxy to it: "127.0.0.1:8888", added a rule for fiddler.exe to connect directly and added a global rule to force everything to connect through 127.0.0.1:8888.

But the traffic doesn't show up on my Fiddler. All that happens is that Fiddler opens lots of certificate errors like this:

[image]

And the HTTPS-requests end in NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

Note that when I use Fiddler for HTTPS traffic without Proxifier, everything works just fine. In Chrome and in Firefox (even without the hook installed). So the Fiddler root certificate should be installed correctly... at least for the browsers?

So what am I doing wrong here? Any idea how to get this to work? Is there maybe alternative software? (Not to Fiddler, but to Proxifier, so please don't tell me to use Wireshark.)

Comment: Another possibility is a transparent proxy, though I haven't set one up before.

Comment: I don't understand. I mean Fiddler is a transparent proxy. My problem is that I'm getting certificate errors.

Comment: So what happens if you disable the warning?

Comment: I don't know, but if I just click okay, the request doesn't seem to go through. And it doesn't show up on Fiddler either..

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution.  I'm also trying to do this, but unable to.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. :/

Comment: Any update on this? I'm also facing the same issue :(

Comment: No, I gave up on it a long time ago and I use Linux these days anyway.. Maybe there is a way to do it in Linux. I should look that up..